# What are secret hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

My question is simply that, *what are secret hats?*  I have seen many users with hats not listed in the winter bash page, the hats' description say “this is a secret hat”.  In fact *most* of the what's I have seen so far are secret hats, what does this mean?

I even just earned the *fascinating* secret hat and still have no idea what it means!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *secret hats* are just hats, like any of the other hats on the [winter page](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), except Stack Exchange did not give the instructions on how to get them.

There is a growing list of spoilers for the secret hats on http://meta.stackexchange.com.

To answer your question about how you got the *fascinating* you can hover your mouse over here.

> for upvoting an accepted answer with 5 votes